# Is scraping comments to form an answer, frowned upon?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1644294/vmware-workstation-does-not-support-nested-virtualization-on-this-host-module/) question has a comment from the OP, suggesting the fix

> @Ramhound thank you, i finally sorted it . the "Windows Hypervisor Platform" needed to be unticked in the windows features... this i had done initially but what i didnt know is that "Virtual Machine Platform" needs to be unticked as well. Simple fix took me 2 days ! :-)

A new user then took that comment, and turned it into a [(poorly formatted) answer](https://superuser.com/a/1651477/603073).

Is this kind of behaviour promoted? Discouraged? Or does it really not matter?

Comment: I've occasionally done this myself (on other SE sites), but only with questions that are years old, and always with explicit mention of the comments and their authors. It feels so wrong to have an "unanswered" question that has perfectly good answers in its comments.

Comment: It it allowed sure, I would argue, the answer isn’t completely correct though or at the very least incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the *polite* thing to do would be to comment and leave the original author a gentle reminder that they could and probably should write a proper answer.

If it is obvious that the question is abandoned by the asker, is old, and it looks like they will never come back then maybe converting a comment to an answer is a "good thing" as it gives future visitors a definite starting point.

In this case though I'm not really fond of the conversion from comment to answer. OP was last seen 10 days ago (15th May) according to their profile so they've definitely been back to see it, not quite abandoned yet.

It feels a little like an attempt to grab points.